# Is Extended Signal Multiplexing supported by Autosar 4.0?

Tags: can-bus, autosar

in CAN netwotrks for Autosar 4.0 complient SW. can Extended Signal Multiplexingbe supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible to multiplex extended CAN IDs. You could configure it as range/ list of IDs for the HRH in CanIf.

Comment: Further if it is a com signal you should use IpduM module to deal with multiplexed signals ;)